# Redirect to Action is not working With ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my login view which wants to redirect to Clients page after successful login.

To do that I am using ,

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.Rememberme, false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    if (Request.Query.Keys.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
                    {
                        Redirect(Request.Query["ReturnUrl"].First());
                    }
                    RedirectToAction("Index", "Clients");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failed to login");
                    return View();
                }
            }

            return View();

        }
```

But after successful login , I am staying in current login page and not redirected to Client Page!! If I try to navigate to Client page using browser this works fine without any issue.

Comment: Its `return RedirectToAction(...);` (your missing the `return`)

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Clients");` => you need to return `RedirectToActionResult` there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to return method result, just add return to all redirect methods:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Clients");
```

Redirect methods are returnig view, to show this view You need to return it.

[More info about IActionResult](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-action-results/)