# When Deploy my site to Production RedirectToAction show a blank page

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-8

Well my site local working well, but when is deployed to production the RedirectToAction fail and show a blank page.

I have tried these 
[Redirect to Action is not working With ASP.NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221704/redirect-to-action-is-not-working-with-asp-net-core)

here is the code:

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.UserViewModel person)
    {
        var booleanlog = Models.Security.User.login.DoLogin(person);
        if (booleanlog!=0) {
            ...
            return View("Index");
        }
        else {

            return View("Login");
        }

    }
```

I already tried this code too and doesn´t work

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.UserViewModel person)
    {
        var booleanlog = Models.Security.User.login.DoLogin(person);
        if (booleanlog != 0) {
            var serializeSession = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(booleanlog);
            HttpContext.Session.Set("Rol", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializeSession));
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        else {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

    }
```

there are my routes configuration
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            } else if(env.IsProduction()) {

```
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

        } else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

and show this

redirect to a root locahost and show error 404 not found

in addition, this work in my local VisualStudio IIS Express, My Local IIS, but doesn´t work in my production IIS

Comment: can you please post the code that you're using?

Comment: but as I can see in your code, you're not using RedirectToAction.

Comment: yes, I change to return View to try if work, but same thing

Comment: are you using MVC or Razor Pages?

Comment: How are your routes configured? What does `HomeController.Index()` look like?

Comment: updated with my routes configuration, and what mean "HomeController.Index() look like? "

Comment: My solution was migrate from .Net Core MVC to .Net Framework MVC and working well

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `return View()`. View() does not return a `RedirectToActionResult` if you specify a different view. You want to `return RedirectToAction()` in your else block.

---

RE: Still doesn't work

Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that explains what parameters need to be passed into `RedirectToAction()`

If you `return RedirectToAction('Login')` you are telling it to return the result from the action on your current controller.

If this is not the desired behavior, you need to provide what 'Login' is.

Comment: "If you return RedirectToAction('Login') you are telling it to return the result from the action on your current controller." yes, is the case when the user enter wrong credential data

Comment: "Login", current controller, login controller

Comment: "Index" the view of home dashbord, only for logged in users

Comment: the curious thing is that this working on my local iis but dint work when I copy the files to production server

Comment: Gotcha.  Can't redirect using `return view()`, so I'm not exactly sure how that could have ever worked. needed to fix that first.  If it's working local in visual studio, and not in IIS, it's almost always a IIS configuration problem on the production server.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.UserViewModel person)
        {
            var booleanlog = Models.Security.User.login.DoLogin(person);
            if (booleanlog != 0) {
                var serializeSession = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(booleanlog);
                HttpContext.Session.Set("Rol", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializeSession));
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
            }
            else {

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            
        }

Comment: this code doesn´t work too, work in mi local Visual Studio, and publishing to my local iis, but not in production."it's almost always a IIS configuration problem on the production server" but wich one configuration? :( so sad

Comment: if you need help getting IIS to work, there's another stackexchange for that https://serverfault.com/